# Exponential congruence for a public key

Tags: congruences

I have this formula as a public key for "T" = 19:

$c \equiv 19^{13}(mod 697)$

But I do not know how to solve it. I tried the exponential property: 
$716\equiv 19(mod 697) \Rightarrow 716^{13}\equiv 19^{13}(mod 697)$

But as it turns out, c = 15.
So, how to solve it? Thank you for your attention.

Comment: Are you familiar with [Euler's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_theorem) ?

Comment: Actually, not that much. I have difficulty to find the totient function.

Comment: The first step is to find the prime factors of the modulus 697.

Comment: Right. If I am not mistaken, the prime factors of 697 are 17 and 41. Then, what is the next step?

Comment: That's correct. So $\phi(697)=(17-1)(41-1)=640$, which is much larger than any power we need to consider in performing this computation. So we can basically ignore it. :) To calculate $c$, do it in stages, reducing by mod 697 as you go. $19^{13}= (19^6)^2\times19$ and $19^6=(19^3)^2$

Comment: But that is the problem. I don't know any integer which is congruent to 19 modulo 697 other than 716 and 19 itself. Does the number needs to be negative, or something?

Comment: Sorry, there's no (obvious) short-cut here. You'll need to compute small powers of 19 and reduce them mod 697. Now $19^2 = 361 < 697$, so that's not much help. But we can multiply that by 19 to get 6859, which can be reduced mod 697 to 586. Then we can square 586 and reduce that, which will give us $19^6 \mod {697}$

Comment: All right. Thanks.